# KnockoutJS: issues validating multiple rows with dropdownlists

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I'm trying validate the two dropdowns that I have on button click. When the dropdowns first initiate, they are initiated with a value of undefined because nothing has been selected. This is what I want. But when I click the add button to validate the dropdowns before I add another row, the validation never occurs.

**JS**

```
 ko.validation.init({
    insertMessages: false,
    errorMessageClass: "ErrorLine"
  });
  ko.validation.rules['bothUndefined'] = {
    getValue: function (o) {
      return (typeof o === 'function' ? o() : o);
    },
    validator: function (val, params) {
      var self = this;

      var anyOne = ko.utils.arrayForEach(params, function (param) {
        if (typeof param === "function") {
            return typeof param() === "undefined";
          } else {
            return (typeof param === "undefined");
          }
        });

      return (typeof anyOne !== "undefined");
    },
    message: 'Please select one change.'
  };
  ko.validation.registerExtenders();

function BookPossessionTransferVM() {
    var self = this;
.
.
.
    self.PossessionChanges  = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.PossessionChangesErrors  =  ko.validation.group(self.PossessionChanges(), { deep: true, live: true });
    self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeVM(self.PossessionChanges().length +1))
.
.
.
self.addPossessionChange = function () {
      if (self.PossessionChanges().length < 1) {
        self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangesVM(self.PossessionChanges().length + 1,
          self.AllFrom()));
      } else {
        self.PossessionChangesErrors.showAllMessages();
      }
    }
}

 function PossessionChangeVM(possessionChangeId) {
    var self = this;

    self.possessionChangeId = ko.observable(possessionChangeId);
    self.SelectedFrom =  ko.validatedObservable();
    self.SelectedTo =  ko.validatedObservable();
self.IsValidRow = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      return typeof self.SelectedFrom !== "undefined" && typeof self.SelectedTo !== "undefined";
    }).extend({
      bothUndefined: {
        params: [self.SelectedFrom, self.SelectedTo]
      }
    });

    self.ChangeType = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      if (self.SelectedFrom() !== undefined && self.SelectedTo() !== undefined) {
        return 'Update';
      } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined && self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
          return '';
      } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined) {
        return 'Add';
      } else if (self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
        return 'Remove';
      } else { return ''; }
    });
  }
```

After I click the add button, I am expecting `PossessionChangesErrors` to have one issue since it should load with undefined options. But I am getting nothing. Thanks again for helping!

**EDIT:**
Now I have the validation working, but I am not able to clear the validation to create a new row once one of the drop downs have been selected. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p6x1nqm5/18/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just didn't have the correct logic for the validation. Here is the new fiddle with the changes. https://jsfiddle.net/zw80kh2n/2/

self.IsValidRow became

```
  self.IsValidRow = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      return (!(self.SelectedFrom() === undefined && self.SelectedTo() === undefined))
    }).extend({      bothUndefined: {}
    });
```

and the validation became

```
ko.validation.rules['bothUndefined'] = {
    getValue: function (o) {
      return (typeof o === 'function' ? o() : o);
    },
    validator: function (val) {
      return val;
    },
    message: 'Please select one change.'
  };
  ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```